# Chinese characters stored incorrectly in mysql while using nihbernate with .Net

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I am trying to store Chinese characters (指事字 zhǐshìzì) through a web form. But mysql database stored them as something like this "??? zhishìzì"

- Value type is NVarChar
- Characterset is utf8
- mysql version is 5.1.52-community

I have seen similar questions posted on stackoverflow. But couldn't find an answer.

Comment: mySql does not have nvarchar...

Comment: Which tool is showing you the faulty data and what exactly does it look like?

Comment: I am storing data using web form. Something like this "指事字 zhǐshìz". After I store it's displays like this ""??? zhishìzì". I am using Database Workbench v4.03 for database administration work.

Comment: You're likely to get more helpful answers if you include your code in the question. How is the form data being processed before it is inserted into the database? What is the query that is being used to insert the data? What is the structure and configuration of the database, table, and fields of the database?

Comment: It's a .Net MVC n application powered by .Net C#. I am using nihbernate for data manipulation.

Comment: You can edit your question, add as much useful information as you can.

Comment: What if you run the query directly in the  Database Workbench v4.03 ? Just to isolate the problem if it lies at the web form part or db part or both.

Comment: Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-B-11-1-2).

Comment: Good point. I tried. Insert data using direct query and it works. I debug the application. In debug mode values are OK showing correctly until saving to database. I am using Nhibernate. Can it be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer my self. problem was connection string.

previously it was like this

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=xxxxx;Database=xxxxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx;Port=xxx</property>
```

I add "CharSet=utf8" to it and it works :)

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=xxxxx;Database=xxxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxxx;Port=xxxx;CharSet=utf8</property>
```

Thank you for your help...!!

Comment: I took 3 fullll Days to resolve this isssue.....dumpu, export, import updates new databases change mysql, use linux ubuntu..editcnf files, and many things... but never thought it can be so simple like u provide solution... thanks a lot... +10000 likes for this, ofcourse need to set collate, but without this solution its useless..